# 'int' is a primitive and doesn't support nested properties: Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to find a substring of a string as a part of an activity in ADF. Say for instance I want to extract out the subsctring `'de'` out of a string `'abcde'`. I have tried:

```
@substring(variables('target_folder_name'), 3, (int(variables('target_folder_name_length'))-3))
```

where `int(variables('target_folder_name_length'))` has a value of 5 and `variables('target_folder_name')` has a value of `'abcde'`

But it gives me: `Unrecognized expression: (int(variables('target_folder_name_length'))-3)`

On the other hand, if I try this: `@substring(variables('target_folder_name'), 2, int(variables('target_folder_name_length'))-3)`

This gives me: `'int' is a primitive and doesn't support nested properties`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use **indexof**. See my example below:

```
@substring(variables('testString'), indexof(variables('testString'), variables('de')), length(variables('de')))
```

[image]

Output of 'result' variable:

[image]

Comment: in my case the value of 'de' is dynamic. It can be anything. The preceding 3 letters are static. I cannot put 'de' in a variable hence.

Comment: where does your 'de' come from? You can probably still use 'set variable' to assign the value to your variable beforehand.

Comment: The entire string name 'abcde' (in this example) comes from a blob storage and the value of 'de' is what I need to find out. Also note that the length of 'de' is variable. It can be 'def' or can be 'defg' also

Comment: Can your pipeline add a 'Set Variable' activity to store your 'variable value' into a variable first? That way, you can make use of variable to do what you need to do. 
Alternatively, do show us your current pipeline so we understand better

Answer (score 0):

Since your preceding values are static, you can use below dynamic expression to achieve the substring value as per your requirement.

```
@substring(variables('varInputFolderName'), 3, sub(length(variables('varInputFolderName')), 3))
```

Where varInputFolderName = String = abcde as per this sample.

Here is the pipeline JSON payload for this sample. You can play around with it for further testing.

```
{
    "name": "pipeline_FindSubstring",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "setSubstringValue",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "varSubstringOutput",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@substring(variables('varInputFolderName'), 3, sub(length(variables('varInputFolderName')), 3))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "varInputFolderName": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "abcde"
            },
            "varSubstringOutput": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```